# Passing variable from JavaScript to Action Class

Tags: javascript, struts

I have a view.jsp and I am declaring a variable (parentUrl) inside JavaScript function in this JSP. I want to pass this variable to my Java Class (MyAction). Here is my code

```
function editAddress(){ 
    var parentUrl=document.referrer;
    request.setAttribute("url", parentUrl);
    document.forms[0].action = "path of the Myaction class";
    document.forms[0].submit();         
}
```

Upon clicking on SAVE button in view.jsp, above function is called that is forwarding my request to MyAction class and MyAction class is then forwarding the request to another jsp page. I want to pass parentUrl variable to be passed in the MyAction class so I can use the value of this variable to write some logic . Here is myAction class code that is retrieving variable value from the request:

```
String parentURL = (String)request.getParameter("url");
```

Basically I want to get the URL of parent page from where the request is coming from. That is why I am using document.referrer function.

My problem is when I add these 2 lines in my function editAddress(), my SAVE button stops working and it is not navigating to another page. I dont know why this happening.

```
var parentUrl=document.referrer;
request.setAttribute("url", parentUrl);
```

Please let me know the any other better way to pass this parentUrl variable to \MyAction class from JavaScript. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you realize that Java and JavaScript are two different languages, that JavaScript is executed at client-side, and Java at server-side? If you want the URL to be submitted, you need to store it in a hidden field or the form, so that it's submitted with the form. Your JS code is invalid, because request is an undefined JS variable.

Answer (score 2):

`request.setAttribute()` is not a javascript method, so you cannot use it this way. Instead, declare a hidden field in your form and set its value to submit.

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="parentURL">
...
</form>

function editAddress(){ 
    var parentUrl=document.referrer;
    document.forms[0].parentURL.value=parentUrl;
    document.forms[0].action = "path of the Myaction class";
    document.forms[0].submit();         
}
```

Declare `parentURL`(getter/setter) in your action class to access its value